# Laptop cannot find any wireless networks

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

Recently and randomly, my laptop running Windows 10 can no longer find any wireless networks at all. What is most confusing is that this problem persists even when I use a USB wifi adapter. I've tested this with multiple USB adapters and both at home and at work. Ethernet works fine.

This makes me think that it is some other network configuration issue somewhere in Windows. I've tried the usual solutions like the Windows troubleshooter, disable/re-enable, and reinstalling drivers.

Are there any other avenues I should investigate? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How long ago did this start happening, approximately?

Comment: When you re-installed drivers, did you uninstall via Device Manager and tick the box _"Delete the driver software for this device"_?  If not, try that, reboot, download the most recent driver from the manufacturer, reinstall, then reboot again.  If that doesn't fix it, it's likely going to be quicker and more efficient to simply do a repair install of Windows (it doesn't remove programs or files, just replaces system files). Download the ISO through Windows Media Creator, launch `setup.exe` while booted to Windows, select the option to upgrade and to keep files and settings.

Comment: Before the reinstall, you can try the following from an Admin terminal: `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`, then issue `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`  Once it completes, reboot, then in an Admin terminal issue: `sfc /scannow`, reboot once it completes, and see if the issue resolves itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unusual problem as it sounds as though different wireless adapters, which would use different drivers, are affected.

It sounds as though something in Windows itself is corrupted.

**First option:**

Try performing a network reset and seeing if the problem persists:

1. Search for `network reset` from the Start menu:

[image]

2. Choose `Reset now`:

[image]

**Second option:**

If the first troubleshooting step fails, try System Restore.

- choose a System Restore point from around a month before you first noticed the problem
- see if the WiFi issue persists

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I tried this and the problem persists.